# Como saber se o video tem direitos autorias atraves do youtube api

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Há como atraves de json descobrir se um determinado video tem direitos autorais pela api do youtube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há sim,

Na própria documentação do [Youtube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#representao-de-recurso), existe uma propriedade de valor *booleano* retornado no *Json* chamada **contentDetails.licensedContent** que mostra se um parceiro de conteúdo do Youtube reivindicou seus direitos de *copyright* ou não sobre o conteúdo, como você pode ver na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Além disso, como adicional a resposta, há também uma propriedade chamada **status.rejectionReason** que retorna uma *String*, cuja a qual o valor visa explicar "O porque o YouTube rejeitou um vídeo enviado" ([isso segundo a mesma documentação](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#representao-de-recurso)). Caso o upload não seja possível devido a implicação de *copyright* o valor retornado na *String* será de "*copyright*".

Esses são os valores das possíveis causas de rejeição que podem ser retornados por essa propriedade:

- claim
- copyright
- duplicate
- inappropriate
- length
- termsOfUse
- trademark

Observação: esta propriedade por sua vez só estará disponível se a propriedade **uploadStatus** indicar que o envio realmente foi rejeitado, ou seja, se o valor da *String* retornado na mesma for igual a "*rejected*".